# The Freshest Tablet

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

*Stories of the theft of the freshest tablet* (5,5,5,5,5)

Given the above, if `L` is a backslash, then what number is `E`?

Hint 1 (minor):

> Both "of the"s are just filler to make the clue words read as a sentence.  Yes, that leaves only four clue words to produce five answer words...

Hint 2 (major):

> Anagrams are involved...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E is:

> 3

Because:

> if we arrange the five words in [Quantum Twinkie's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79761/39764) so that the Ls form a backslash so:
>
>  **L**EAST
>  S**L**ATE
>  TA**L**ES
>  STA**L**E
>  STEA**L**
>
>  and then draw lines connecting the Es, it looks like a "3".
>
>  [image: The letters in question connected by lines]

Comment: You got it!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

Is it related to

> Tales, Steal, Least Stale, Slate?

Because

> A synonym (as [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79737/the-freshest-tablet/79738#79738) mentioned) of stories is tales. The anagrams of tales are steal(theft), (least stale(freshest), and slate(tablet). This would make 5 five letter words.

For the final part,

> If we uses tales to reference the l as a "\", we could look at t for [, a for ], l for \, e for 7, and s for 8, on a keyboard with a number pad. This way, E would be a number. But, it is a big jump....

Comment: Yep, that's the first half solved...

Comment: @jasonharper, do I have the answer? :)

Comment: No, it's nothing related to keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

I think this puzzle involves

> finding five words of five letters each (hence "5,5,5,5,5"), probably by paraphrasing the phrase we've been given.

More specifically,

> "Stories" could become TALES, and "of the" could be ABOUT. Maybe "tablet" is STONE (in the sense of an ancient clay tablet)? THEFT is already 5 letters, but maybe we still need to paraphrase it. Not sure about "freshest".

Comment: The intermediate answer is five separate words - I've reworded the clue a bit so as not to suggest a word square.

Comment: @jasonharper aww, word square would've been cool :-( OK, edited my answer.

Comment: Freshest could be rot13(pehqr, lbhat, be svefg)?

Answer (score 2):

This is heavily based on @Rupert Morrish’s answer, because

> The backslash is the character \, not /. The answer is still 3, though!

So, by following their method:

> If we arrange the five words in Quantum Twinkie's answer so that the Ls form a backslash so: 
>  LEAST 
>  SLATE 
>  TALES 
>  STALE 
>  STEAL 
>  and then draw lines connecting the Es, it looks like a "3".